# List of Cloudfoundry Services not showing Mongo 2.0

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry

In my deployments config directory I see two versions of MongoDB (1.8 and 2.0). However when I run

> vmc services

from my client, only 1.8 shows up (presumably because it is default).  I tried changing the default in mongodb_gateway.yml (and node.yml), but after a restart the list is unchanged.

Any idea how I can get Mongo 2.0 to show up as a provisionable service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I removed 1.8 from the mongodb_node.yml and mongodb_gateway.yml files and then restarted cloud foundry, 2.0 (and 1.8) appeared.  The problem is that there's no way to differentiate the two, so it appears to use what you have set as the default version in the yml files. At any rate it shows up now.